# How to pass argument when using .agg() method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, data-science, data-analysis

Currently this is my code to find variance and mean of a particular column in a dataframe

```
categorize_data = dataset['dayNumber'].between(1, 7)
grouped_priority = dataset[categorize_data].groupby('priority')
grouped_priority.agg({'serviceTime':['var','mean' ] , 'travelTime':['var','mean' ] }).reset_index()
```

In this code `var` function which has a positional argument `ddof` which is `1` by default but I want to pass that `ddof` as `0`.

How to achieve this using .agg() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom lambda function:

```
var1 = lambda x: x.var(ddof=0)
grouped_priority.agg({'serviceTime':[var1,'mean'] , 
                      'travelTime':[var1,'mean'] }).reset_index()
```

Comment: I have used np.var but still getting the same value (which I was already getting with 'var').

But the second option is working fine.

Thank you